# How to configure ListenHTTP processor to send a success response with the return code?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a ListenHTTP processor that is configured to listen on port 8443 and accept any client. I want to configure the processor to send a success response with the return code when it successfully processes an HTTP request. How can I do this?

My current config is:
[ListenHTTP configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfLxa.png)

currently there's no response
I want my response to be this in json format:
{
"status": "OK"
}

Comment: The ListenHTTP has a `Return Code` property that's defaulted to 200 which translates to OK, are you looking for something else ? Did you try sending in a message to the listener and check the response via Postman ?

Comment: Yes currently there's an empty response, only the code is being sent. I want an additional JSON response to be sent

Comment: In this case you would have to use the `HandleHttpRequest` tagged with `HandleHttpResponse` to be able to send a custom response body.